# Text wrapped in FittedBox becomes tiny on small screens

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have this text widget which is wrapped in a FittedBox:

```
FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: color,
            fontWeight: fontWeight,
            fontSize: fontSize ?? Screen.heightUnit(context) * 3.5,
            fontFamily: fontFamily,
            shadows: [
              Shadow(
                color: shadowColor.withOpacity(shadow ? 1.0 : 0.0),
                blurRadius: blurRadius,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
```

The resulting text looks great, no matter the screen size it fit perfectly, except if the screen is small. From all the screens provided by the Device Preview package, the only one with a problem is the "Small Phone" one, and testing it on my physical device, which has a small screen too, also has a problem. In those cases, instead of the text being the perfect size, it is too small to the point of being hard to read.

[Expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zrqj.png)

[Bad behavior on small screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxP6N.png)

Changing the fit parameter doesn't change anything, unless I change it to BoxFit.none, in which case the FittedBox magic just stops working altogether. Changing the font size doesn't do almost anything either.

The card where the text is located:

```
class FoodWidget extends CustomCard {
  FoodWidget(
    context, {
    this.foodWidth,
    @required this.food,
  }) : super(
          height: Screen.heightUnit(context) * 8,
          width: foodWidth ?? Screen.widthUnit(context) * 83,
          padding: 15,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              CustomTextWidget(
                food.name,
                color: Themes.cardHeader(context),
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  CustomTextWidget(
                    food.calories.toString(),
                    color: Themes.cardContent(context),
                  ),
                  CustomTextWidget(
                    ' kcal',
                    color: Themes.cardConstantUnit(context),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
  final double foodWidth;
  final Food food;
}
```

CustomCard:

```
return Card(
  shadowColor: Colors.black,
  color: Themes.cardBackground(context),
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius)),
  elevation: elevation,
  child: Container(
    height: height ?? Screen.heightUnit(context) * 12.5,
    width: width ?? Screen.widthUnit(context) * 20.5,
    alignment: alignment,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(padding),
    child: child,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out what was wrong. While all the values were using my custom made size units for height and width (Screen.heightUnit and Screen.widthUnit) that were made to be proportional to the screen size, the padding parameter of FoodWidget was hard-coded with the value of 15 pixels, which is not proportional to screen size, hence the bad behavior on small screens.